# Rate limit based on VLAN

Tags: vlan, qos, bandwidth, isp, design

My ISP company has some PoPs in remote areas, as shown in diagram. It is currently, it's getting all prefixes from Local IX and getting only a default route from the upstream Internet provider. Currently, the internal network uses static routing, but I am planning to move it to OSPF.

Currently, all the traffic shaping is done in PoP routers so that core router doesn't get burned out, and it's done by interface-based rate limiting, one customer one interface basis.

Now my goal is to provide unlimited speed (full wire-speed) to local IX, which gives hundreds of prefixes which are constantly changing, and my service nodes (FTP, storage, local contents, etc.), while limiting Internet bandwidth by customer. Preferably, this done in the PoP routers. Again, it is not at all feasible to put separate long haul links to pop routers just for this purpose.

Is it possible to rate limit based on VLAN so that I can achieve the goal? Are there any other suggestions?

[image]

Comment: This question is really broad with opinion-based answers. You can read in the [help] on how to properly ask a question, and you should edit your question to narrow the focus and eliminate opinion-based answers.

Comment: Edited to narrow question down

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible rate limit based on vlan so I can achieve the goal ?

The answer is a qualified yes. It really depends on the capabilities of your router hardware and software. For instance, I know Cisco and Juniper routers have robust QoS features to allow traffic shaping and policing based on a variety of criteria, which include VLANs or IP address ranges.

Without knowing what equipment you are using, it is impossible to say for sure, but it is highly probable that you can do this.